# Implement Entity Framework level one caching explicitly

Tags: entity-framework, caching

Can we implement first level caching in Entity framework 6 (later on 7) explicitly,

Idea may be; by intercepting add or get call in Entity framework.

Comment: working with 6 right now , may be on 7 after release.

Comment: As I understand it DbContext is a 1st level cache. You could wrap the context in a collection like repository and implement caching. Is there a reason it needs to be 1st level cache?

Comment: I have not tried this but you should be able to implement cached Add, Find, etc if your context implements custom IDbSet<T> property types.
Instead of 
IDbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
you have
class CustomerSet : IDbSet<Customer>
{}

Seems like a lot of work.

Comment: seems convenient but looking to implement this in more generic way

Comment: Well you could have something like CustomerSet : CachedDbSet<Customer> and have a generic caching strategy in a custom type called CachedDbSet<T> . Personally I prefer my caching to be at an application level. So if I have a CustomerService I would have interception points on the message calls of the service. You specified level 1 caching though so my comments above are best I can think of.

Comment: @deebo  I agree with your point as after having quiet detailed view of EF 6 code, I concluded that it is better to  implement object caching at second level instead of changing implementation first level cache.